# How can I list all members from AD group showing enable and disabled users?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-5.0

I'm trying get a list of all members from a AD Group showing active \ inactive users. The purpose is get all the members on the groups and list the ones with Admin privileges.

I did the following commands:

```
$GROUPNAME = "Domain Admins" 
Get-ADGroupMember -identity $GROUPNAME -Recursive | Select name, SamAccountName, objectclass | Sort-Object Name
```

Tried to combine with Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} but I need the first cmdlet to output for me Users, so I can filter with Get-ADuser.

Tks in advance

Comment: What about pulling the output from Get-ADGroupMember to a variable $USERS and then running a ForEach loop that pulls them through Get-ADUser to check for Enabled? I'm playing with this now modifying a script that is similar-ish, but haven't worked out the kinks yet.

Comment: @music2myear Seems that worked!
Did the following:
`$GROUPNAME = 'Domain Admins'`

`Get-ADGroupMember -identity $GROUPNAME -Recursive | Select name, SamAccountName, objectclass | Sort-Object Name`

`foreach ($USERS in $USERS) { Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false } | Select Name, Enabled, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName }`

Comment: Sweet, write that up as the answer. I may have pointed you in the right direction, but you solved it.

Comment: Though, I'd personally leave off the Select and Sort-object off of the first line. Get-ADGroupMember is outputting objects which Get-ADUser should be able to handle just fine, and the Select command on the last line should be sufficient.

Comment: Did some tests here but seems that statement:

`Get-ADGroupMember -identity $GROUPNAME -Recursive` is not getting all the members from Domain Admins group or whatever group on the cmdlet. With last cmdlet filtering results just show disabled users at general on AD.

Comment: In the code you've posted it doesn't look as though you writing the contents of Domain Admins to a variable, and then you're just looping through every user account in the domain with Get-ADUser.

Comment: It seems that you doing the command `Get-ADGroupMember -identity $GROUPNAME` without recursive option shows the members. Just does not show a group inserted into the Domain Admins members.

Comment: @music2myear I tested these cmdlets and seems to be working now!
Unfortunatelly I can't vote for my own reply, if you could do will be appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did this way:

```
$groupname = "Domain Admins"
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}
foreach ($activeusers in $users) { Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | ? {$_.enabled -eq $true} | select Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled }
```

If you want disabled just replace last cmdlet:

```
foreach ($activeusers in $users) { Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | ? {$_.enabled -eq $false} | select Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled }
```

Comment: How to add the export csv portion here?

Answer (score 1):

using Marlon's answer above. if you want to output it as a list to text or CSV you can do this:

```
$groupname = "Domain Admins"
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}
$result = @()
foreach ($activeusers in $users) { $result += (Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | ? {$_.enabled -eq $true} | select Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled) }
$result | Export-CSV  -NoTypeInformation .\active_domain_admins.csv
```

you can switch the last line to this, if you just want output to a text file:

```
$result | Out-File .\active_domain_admins.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$GrpName = '[Group Name]'
$ExportPath = 'C:\\Temp\\' + $GrpName + '-GroupMembers.csv'
$Grp = Get-ADGroup $GrpName | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Name,Mail,Enabled  | Select-Object Name,Mail,Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $True}
$Grp.Count
$Grp | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

Answer (score 1):

My "oneliner". Thanks for answers above.

```
$GROUPNAME = "Domain Admins" 
Get-ADGroupMember $GROUPNAME | Get-ADUser | Where-Object -Property enabled -eq $true | select name
```